# Creating Pages and adding webpart to sections of page (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, graph-api, logic-app

When a List Item is created, I wish to automate the provisioning of a SharePoint Site and add pages with webparts to sections of the page (webparts pre-loaded onto tenant). Because Modern Sites do not allow templates (like classic sites) another method is needed. So considering 4 options as listed below - Please confirm if my understanding us correct or there are other methods available.

1. **PowerAutomate (REST API)** - Can create sites but cannot create pages nor add webparts to pages
2. **PowerAutomate (Graph API)** -  Not sure of capability
3. **Site Designs**  - Cannot add pages
4. **PnP library** - This can work if manually creating through PowerShell but how can I automate, is the option Logic Apps ?

Another overlay to the above options is to 'Clone / Copy' an existing site. I know this is possible with PnP but again I need to automate it without firing up PowerShell application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Azure Automation, we could run the powershell using PowerAutomate.

1. Create Automation account in Azure with a Run Book to execute PowerShell script
2. Use Power automate flow to call the Run Book

You could refer to this article for more: https://ashiqf.com/2020/05/26/execute-sharepoint-online-powershell-scripts-using-power-automate/

Comment: I've seen some documentation that ties in Power Automate > Logic Apps > Function App. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs
Whats the relationship of the above and Azure Automation, is Azure Automation an old way of working ?